# Deleting content in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a blog with Codeigniter and I'm having trouble deleting categories. I can create them, edit them, but I can't remove them. I get this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: models/article_model.php
>
> Line Number: 167
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: F:\wamp64\www\site\application\models\article_model.php Line:
>   167 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: F:\wamp64\www\site\application\controllers\admin\categories.php
>   Line: 85 Function: delete_category
>
> File: F:\wamp64\www\site\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS NULL' at line 3

DELETE FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '5' AND IS NULL

Filename: F:/wamp64/www/site/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

I'm using PHP7 and CodeIngiter 3.1.3

Here is the code from my article_model.php

```
public function delete_category($id){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('categories', $data); // this is line 167
    return true;
}
```

Here is the code from categories.php

```
public function delete($id){
    $this->Article_model->delete_category($id); // this is line 85

    //Create Message
    $this->session->set_flashdata('category_deleted', 'Your category has been deleted');

    //Redirect to articles
    redirect('admin/categories');
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do it like this

```
$this->db->delete('categories', array('id' => $id));
```

you could also write it as:

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->delete('categories');
```

the `$data` array is needed for inserts or updates only, for deleting you just use e.g. the `id` of the row in question